# From which aircraft does this vintage altimeter come from?

Tags: military, aircraft-identification, altimeter

I bought this vintage U.S. Navy Kollsman altimeter at a market in Bangkok, Thailand.

[image]
Unfortunately, I don't have any info other than what you see in the photos.

[image]
It's a Kollsman altimter and the model or serial number is KO-67ICLU-035 Type/6433 MB-I

[image]
There is another serial number(?) on the scale which reads MS28044LI, and below ALT it reads 50,000FT.

[image]
Here's another clue: This sticker says the altimeter was serviced in the PNCLA (Pensacola) 89771 NAVAL AIR REWORK FACILITY in the 3rd fiscal quarter of 1981.

[image]
Another sticker says it was tested at the Naval Air Rework Facility Pensacola (NARF) and found to be free of radioactivity, also in 1981.

[image]
Finally, S/N-71 is embossed on the backside of the altimeter.

So what type of aircraft could this instrument have been part of?

Comment: Instruments are often not built for a specific airplane, this could have been used on any number of aircraft.

Comment: Yes, I know. I was hoping the stamps would provide some clues. I think we're looking at a U.S. Navy aircraft that has likely been in service in Southeast Asia sometime in the 70s/80s.

Comment: I found a manual for it http://www.liberatedmanuals.com/TM-55-6610-247-40.pdf from the U.S. _Army_. Could this possibly help narrow it down?

Comment: The MS in MS28044L1 stands for military standard.

Comment: My current guess: https://olive-drab.com/idphoto/id_photos_th55_osage.php. But I have failed to find hard evidence for the U.S. Navy using them.

Comment: The fact that it was tested in Pensacola probably doesn’t mean much. NAS Pensacola was home to the Naval Aviation Depot Pensacola until 1993. There were probably a whole lot of maintenance parts from many different aircraft that passed through there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you have is a Kollsman C-12 altimeter manufactured by the Square D Company in Elmhurst, New York. The 50,000 FT marking below the Military Standard number means that the altimeter is accurate up to 50,000 feet of altitude but this number might far exceed the capabilities of a particular aircraft as it was universally used on many different types. The free of radioactivity sticker means that this instrument does not have the radium dials found on earlier models (common on WW-2 instruments) or, was later retro-fitted with a non radium face. Since you purchased this instrument in Thailand I am suggesting it came from a T-28 Trojan. The Royal Thai Air Force operated 120 T-28s from 1962 to 1988. The United States Navy ceased T-28 operations in 1984 but by then many of their T-28Bs  had been modified into "Ds" as counter insurgency aircraft and shipped abroad. Since the Thai Air Force recieved all their aircraft from America, there is a excellent possibility that your instrument came to Thailand either in a ex Navy T-28 or as a spare in a support maintenance package.

Comment: Well, that seems to make sense. I think the Tango Squadron Museum in Chiang Mai has at least one T-28 on display, so I might as well check it out next time I head over there. And thank you for the info, I appreciate it!

Comment: You're welcome, and take your instrument with you to the museum. They might have a a maintenance manual or parts reference index that would help identify your instrument. BTY, the T-28 is a real gentleman's aircraft and a pleasure to fly..

Comment: Could you perhaps explain how you came to "as it was universally used on many different types [including the T-28 Trojan]"?

Comment: The C-12 altimeter was the one quintessential instrument found on a multitude of aircraft from WW-2 fighters and bombers to more modern aircraft before the advent of the glass cockpit.  Search aircraft cockpits photos and this instrument will be seen in most aircraft except the newer glass cockpits.